# Is it better to use <body onEvent=""> or <script>window.onevent=function(){}?</script>

Tags: javascript, html, events, onload

I've tried googling but I'm having trouble expressing what i'm asking.

There seem to be different ways to trigger events and I was wondering if there's a difference between them.

On way is for example:

```
window.onload=function(){headerAdjustWidth();thumbsArrange();checkHash();}
window.onscroll=function(){windowScrollStore();}
window.onresize=function(){headerAdjustWidth();thumbsArrange();windowScrollAdjust();showExpanded(false);}
window.onkeydown=function(){checkKeyboard();}
```

And another way is

```
<body onKeyDown="checkKeyboard();" onLoad="headerAdjustWidth();thumbsArrange();checkHash();" onScroll="windowScrollStore();" onResize="headerAdjustWidth();thumbsArrange();windowScrollAdjust();showExpanded(false);">
```

Are there any pros/cons to each so far?

The other thing is for the onload functions, is there any reason why I should/shouldn't just put them straight in a <script> thing? e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  headerAdjustWidth();
  thumbsArrange();
  checkHash();
</script>
```

Finally, is there any reason why I should do window.onscroll=function(){windowScrollStore();} rather than window.onscroll=windowScrollStore?

Comment: One of the main difference between using `onload` and a `<script>` tag is that this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. You can also have a single `onload` event handler, so if another piece of JavaScript decides to use `onload`, your code will be blown away. That's one of the reason why a lot JS frameworks provide alternative events such as [`jQuery.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thank you, I've gone with putting it all in the <script> tag but not using onload, my functions have been written to not rely on assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view, it is much better to not include calls of javascript within HTML because this makes several building steps complicated such as OFFUSCATION of code.

I highly recommand to use the solution to keep javascript within javascript.

Concerning onload function, as described abode, I function on scripts as it simplificates building process.